# Apache WebDAV Authentication with ubuntu user?

Tags: ubuntu, server, webdav, ubuntu-server

Currently, I am working with Apache WebDAV and its authenticated with apache configuration itself.
Are there any ways to authenticate with ubuntu user credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAM Authentication is one solution for the question.

Reference available here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZdCzKYsgio